# cookie wont be deleted in php

Tags: php, browser, cookies

I set a cookie to delete as the user presses the logout link:

```
  if(isset($_GET['logout']))
  {
       setCookie("user",'',time()-(60*60*24*365*5));
                echo "deleted cookie";
  }
```

When I click logout, I get the writing deleted cookie,.. when I launch the browser again, my logged in screen appears, even thought it shouldnt cause the cookie was deleted.. Why does that happen?

**Edit**: The original `setcookie()` call:

```
setCookie("user",$password_hash,time()+60*60*24*365*5,"/");
```

I even do this:

```
setCookie("user",'',time()-(60*60*24*365*5));
                echo "deleted cookie";
                echo $_COOKIE["user"];
```

The cookie still gets printed

Comment: Show the code you used to set the cookie in the first place.  The path and domain must match exactly if you specified them as well. Also be sure you haven't produced any output before calling `setcookie()` to delete it

Comment: setCookie("user",$password_hash,time()+60*60*24*365*5,"/");

Comment: `$_COOKIE` always contains the value of cookies when your script was requested. Using `setcookie()` to delete a cookie does not unset the `$_COOKIE` variable. That's totally ok. On the next request you will see that. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265 and http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified the path as `"/"` in the original `setcookie()` call, send the same path statement in your unset call:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
     // Delete cookie from browser
     setCookie("user",'',time()-(60*60*24*365*5), "/");

     // Unset the cookie value in context of the running script
     unset($_COOKIE['user']);

     echo "deleted cookie";
}
```

Comment: Your code, seems to be working..and ekrembk..unset method works..I read that / is not necessary.. I guess the authors of the php cookbook were wrong

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
unset($_SESSION);
unset($_COOKIE);
```

and that should make it so that the user has to log back in.

Comment: Delete the file-system and then restarting the server make the user to need to login back again as well. That's really not a useful answer, it has nothing to do with deleting a cookie in the browser.

Comment: -1 This will not work. The `$_COOKIE` superglobal is effectively read-only. http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php